# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined | SectionList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I am trying to populate a section list with three sections. The first two will scroll horizontally and the last will scroll vertically. I believe the only way to do this is to have a FlatList nested inside the section, however, I am getting the above error.

### SECTION LIST CODE

```
  <SectionList
    sections={sections}
    renderItem={({ item, section }) => {
      if (section.index === 0) {
        return renderCategories(section);
      } else if (section.index === 1) {
        return renderPopular(section);
      } else {
        return renderRecent(section);
      }
    }}
    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
  />
```

### RENDER CODE

```
const renderCategories = ({ section }) => {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={section.items}
        horizontal
        renderItem={({ item }) => <CategoryCard item={item} />}
      />
    );
  };

  const renderPopular = ({ section }) => {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={section.items}
        horizontal
        renderItem={({ item }) => <PopularOfferCard item={item} />}
      />
    );
  };

  const renderRecent = ({ section }) => {
    return <RecentOfferCard item={section.item} />;
  };
```

### SECTION DATA

```
  const sections = [
    { index: 0, type: "categories", title: null, items: categories },
    { index: 1, type: "popular", title: null, items: popularOffers },
    { index: 2, type: "recent", title: "Recently Added", items: latestOffers },
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly passing the section property to the renderCategories, renderPopular, renderRecent functions and de-structuring it. It should be like below

```
  <SectionList
    sections={sections}
    renderItem={({ item, section }) => {
      if (section.index === 0) {
        return renderCategories({ section });
      } else if (section.index === 1) {
        return renderPopular({ section });
      } else {
        return renderRecent({ section });
      }
    }}
    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
  />
```

Also please change the section format to below:

```
const sections = [{ index: 0, type: "categories", title: null, data: categories },
{ index: 1, type: "popular", title: null, data: popularOffers },
{ index: 2, type: "recent", title: "Recently Added", data: latestOffers },];
```

Comment: This gives same result.

Comment: Oh no., Could you kindly provide the section data in this line sections={sections}. May be mock data is also fine

Comment: added DATA MODEL.

Comment: Could you change the sections to below and try? 
  `const sections = [
    { index: 0, type: "categories", title: null, data: categories },
    { index: 1, type: "popular", title: null, data: popularOffers },
    { index: 2, type: "recent", title: "Recently Added", data: latestOffers },
  ];`

Comment: Just replace items with data. And also Please keep the main solution as it is i.e., `return renderCategories({ section }); return renderPopular({ section }); return renderRecent({ section });`

Comment: this has solved the error however, no data is showing up :/

Comment: I am suspecting there will be an issue with stylings:) Could you check them once?

Comment: Not the styling unfortunately, I changed back to flatlist and they reappeared.

Comment: Hmm., got it. I will also check it. As the main issue is resolved, could you accept the answer

Comment: Please add changing the items to data in your answer : )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254314/discussion-between-gavara-suneel-and-david-henry).